# How to connect to Remote machine to do distributed testing in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I want to execute my test in remote machine. I know that all the clients machine IP should be in same subnet. With other network is it possible?

Comment: I think it is possible with `Public IPs`. If the remote machine has public ip, then you can connect to it. It is like you are accessing the websites in the internet, which are remote, but they have public IPs. Also, make sure that Firewall is NOT blocking the incoming connections. (Note: I have worked on AWS machines, which have Public IPs, so I used to connect remotely)